# How can i redirect users that are from the us to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I have two html pages, one is pt-BR.html and the other is en-us.html. I want to redirecr US visitors to the en-us.html page and the brazilian visitors to the pt-BR.html page.

I tried searching, but nothing good or free came up.

Comment: Use the browser's location API and/or IP geolocation on the server to get the user's location. Then do the appropriate redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server-side scripting to perform IP geolocation and redirect the page based on the country.

I don't know which language you are using on your server. In this case, you can use the free online tool below to generate scripts in PHP, Perl, Ruby, Python, and .htaccess.

https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-redirection